# Blend modes for composing images?

Tags: image-processing, image

I'm looking for a way to combine two images with standard image [blending methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes) like Darken, Color Burn, Color Dodge, Soft Light. Is there a way to achieve these with `ImageCompose` or `Overlay`?

Answer (score 7):

Use `ImageApply` with a list of images. You just need to get the formula right.

An example of "Screen" mode:

```
blend["Screen", u_, l_] := 1. - (1. - u)*(1. - l)
ImageBlend[mode_String, upper_Image, lower_Image] := 
 ImageApply[blend[mode, #1, #2] &, {upper, lower}]
```

An example to play with "Screen" mode:

```
lowerImg = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
upperImg = 
  ImageAdjust@
   GaussianFilter[Image[RandomReal[1., ImageDimensions@lowerImg]], 
    4.];

ImageBlend["Screen", lowerImg, upperImg]
```

[image: lena blended with noise]

Comment: Can you add color dodge?